# Possible to get when a facebook friend request was issued?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The friend_request stream contains 2 fields - uid_from and uid_to. There's no date info on when the request was made.

Is ther any other table that contains that information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got word back on the Facebook forums - it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can track that yourself, on a going forward basis, but subscribing to friend events. The subscribe API falls under the "real-time" updates. Not sure what you are trying to do.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime

Comment: Yeah - tracking myself is what I am doing, but the events seem to be helpful - I may use them for other things. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at http://facebook.com/me?and=you for new friends it shows their date added. This is public data and has to be stored openly somewhere!!