# How to get the time a friend was made?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I am in the process of creating an app, and one of the pieces of data that I need is the time when a user made a certain friend. So for example do an FQL query where I return the Uid of the friend and the timestamp (date, time) of when that friend was added. I preferably want to do this for all friends of a user.

I have looked through the FQL documentation but wasn't able to find anything about time (other than friend_request but that is only for pending friend requests) and I can't seem to find anything in the Open Graph API either. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to go look in the user's wall and look for the entry "X became friends with Y" posting that facebook puts on there.  However with the spotty results we get from pagination of the feed and the limit of how far back we can go, it's not going to be an exact science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through many facebook forums, facbook bug reporter, facebook blog and facebook developers docs. And came to conclusion.

Currently Facebook doesn't provide either [time a friend request made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989269/possible-to-get-when-a-facebook-friend-request-was-issued) or the time a friend was made(friend request is accepted). It comes under [facebook  privacy policy](http://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/).

Comment: yes at this point I have to agree with you. I asked this question a while ago and since then I have had to change the idea I was working on :(